# Text To Columns for variable number of lines

Tags: excel, vba

The code attached below is to split text to columns. I get an error when I run this code.
The data to be split is as follows:

```
NAME,1244
  NAME,4356
  NAME,5678
```

The number of lines with NAME is variable. I get run time error 1004, No data was selected to parse. How to solve this?

```
Sub SplitNameToColumns()
Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("F2").Select
    For Counter = 1 To rowCount Step 1

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SplitAndScatter()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

This is taken and modified from another question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799180/split-cells-in-several-columns-with-excel-formulas/20799357#20799357).

Let us know if this helps.